# Cleaning characters out of arbitrary nested dictionary(from JSON)

Tags: python, json, dictionary, recursion

I want to clean a `dictionary` that is from a `json` object to remove all the `\n` and `|` characters so that I can use the `csv` `DictWriter` to write it out as a line in a flat-file for a copy into an AWS Database.  I've never used recursion on a `dict` object before, and I'm struggling to figure out how to effectively move through all levels until they are a single string, and then iterate through a list of items that I want to replace.  With my code I'm currently receiving an `IndexError` saying my string index is out of range.  Here is my function:

```
def purge_items(in_iter, items):
    if isinstance(in_iter, dict):
        for k, v in in_iter:
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                purge_items(k[v], items)
    elif isinstance(in_iter, list):
        for item in items:
            for elem in in_iter:
                try:
                    elem.replace(item[0], item[1])
                except AttributeError:
                    continue
    else:
        try:
            for item in items:
                in_iter.replace(item[0], item[1])
        except AttributeError:
            return
```

This function is expecting a dictionary (after I figure it out with a dictionary I want to make it more general to accept any mutable) with arbitrary nested length, and then a list of the items you want to replace in the following form ('\n', ' '), where the second entry is what you are replacing it with.

An example of the data I'm working with is below, with newlines included:

```
{'issuetype': {'avatarId': 22101,
                                      'description': 'A problem found in '
                                                     'production which impairs '
                                                     'or prevents the '
                                                     'functions of the '
                                                     'product.',
                                      'iconUrl': 'https://instructure.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=22101&avatarType=issuetype',
                                      'id': '1',
                                      'name': 'Bug',
                                      'self': 'https://instructure.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issuetype/1',
                                      'subtask': False}}
```

Comment: I want to clean out any instances of newlines or pipes so I can write out to a csv file for loading into a database.  Is there a module that will clean up JSON like that?

Comment: Sure, IF it is valid JSON or Python's dict object. But in Your question You say Your function takes as an input dictionary, yet as an example You pasted not quite valid JSON. Could You be more specific about input? Is it text(string) from file for example, Python's dictionary, valid JSON, malformed JSON...etc

Comment: What I pasted was a segment, imagine an outer '{}' around it.  Each object is huge, so I just pasted a smaller portion:)  It is valid, see edit

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are plenty of modules in general handling and playing with text, to mention only a few:

- ast and it's `ast.literal_eval()`
- textwrap and it's `textwrap.dedent()`
- json

but in Your case simple:

```
test = """
    {'issuetype': {'avatarId': 22101,
                                      'description': 'A problem found in '
                                                     'production which impairs '
                                                     'or prevents the '
                                                     'functions of the '
                                                     'product.',
                                      'iconUrl': 'https://instructure.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=22101&avatarType=issuetype',
                                      'id': '1',
                                      'name': 'Bug',
                                      'self': 'https://instructure.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issuetype/1',
                                      'subtask': False}
                                      }
    """

print ("".join([obj.strip().replace('|', '') for obj in test.split("\n")]))
```

output

```
{'issuetype': {'avatarId': 22101,'description': 'A problem found in ''production which impairs ''or prevents the ''functions of the ''product.','iconUrl': 'https://instructure.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=22101&avatarType=issuetype','id': '1','name': 'Bug','self': 'https://instructure.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issuetype/1','subtask': False}}
```

should suffice, does it?

Ooops, not quite, double " ' ' " needs to be removed too - corrected version:

```
test_1 = "".join([obj.strip().replace('|', '') 
                 for obj in test.split("\n")])
test_2 = test_1.replace("''", "")
print (test_2)
```

output

```
{'issuetype': {'avatarId': 22101,'description': 'A problem found in production which impairs or prevents the functions of the product.','iconUrl': 'https://instructure.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=22101&avatarType=issuetype','id': '1','name': 'Bug','self': 'https://instructure.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issuetype/1','subtask': False}}
```

Comment: I need to be able to descend to arbitrary depths of nesting though, and there could be list of dicts, dict of dicts, etc...

Comment: How about You post an example of such deep nesting with dicts, lists etc, so we could see, and find out some nice solution?